# Parsing non-standard date/time data in an Excel spreadsheet cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for some advice on this one more than anything. I have a spreadsheet that contains store hours for each location at work. The formats range from this:

```
"Mon-Sat 9:30am-9:00pm 
Sunday 11:00am-6:00pm"
```

To the extreme of this:

```
"Mon-Thurs 9:30am-9:00pm 
Fri & Sat 9:30am-11:00pm
Sunday 9:30am-6:00pm
Stat Hol 11:00am-6:00pm"
```

The priority of this cell is to be in human-readable format, but I need to parse this data to display which hour the store closes (always 6PM, 9PM, or 11PM) for each day of the week.

Is it better to modify this data into a date/time format that Excel likes, then concatenate it for the human-readable cell, or is it possible (or even preferred) to parse the existing data to get these closing times without changing the format?

Comment: You should change the data to be uniform (if not following a predefined standard), and restrict future entry to enforce the pattern chosen. Trying to parse what are basically ransom strings would be a nightmare (IMO anyway).

Comment: I would either build a lookup list that includes each variation you run into (add as necessary), associated with a list of included days that you can use to drive a formula, or go directly to an expanded list of included days in an adjacent cell, possibly via lookup or the formulas would be nuts. For example Mon-Sat could be translated to 234567. Once you have each included day in a form you can find, you have the basis for what you need.  For Tuesday's time, find the entry that contains 3 and parse the closing time from the data record.

Comment: David, the question, as asked, really isn't on-topic.  You're asking for brainstorming of possible approaches, which is the kind of thing people can respond to in a comment, but there is no right answer.  An on-topic question would be based on selecting an approach, trying to solve it, and asking for help with a specific Excel problem you can't figure out.

Comment: @fixer1234 I've asked for no such thing. Advice on a best approach is perfectly valid and can be answered outside of a comment. Nothing in my question prohibits someone from providing a working solution in an answer, just as your first comment could be elaborated on for clarity in its own answer.

Comment: OK, I accepted the challenge.  :-)  The general concept in my comment is expanded in an answer.

Comment: It would be pretty simple to extract the data you need, given the formats you have.  I would use VBA and probably regular expressions; fill in the blank days if there are two days on a line, and output the results in a table.  You might even set up a user defined object (Class) which would be simple, easy to maintain, but perhaps overkill for what you are doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a User Defined function that can parse the data in the formats you show, and "fill in the blanks".  It returns an array of values -- one time for each day of the week, plus an entry for "hol". If a particular day's closing time is not defined, the item will contain a null string `""`.

To use this formula, you would enter `=ClosingTime($B2)` as an array formula across a horizontal range of eight cells.  In the example below, you would enter the formula in `C2`.  Then select `C2:J2`.  Finally, confirm by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  You could then, with `c2:j2` selected, drag down for as many locations as needed.

The UDF uses a regular expression to parse the data.  If there are two weekday names in a line, it fills in the days between them with the same closing time; if only a single weekday, then it just fills in that weekday.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

---

```
Option Explicit
Function ClosingTime(S As String)
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(?:(?:\b(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun|hol).*\b(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun|hol))|\b(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun|hol)).*?(\b\d+:?\d*)p"
    Dim arWkDays As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim V(0 To 7) As Variant

For I = 0 To 7
    V(I) = ""
Next I

arWkDays = VBA.Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Hol")

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        For Each M In MC
            With WorksheetFunction
            'submatches 0-1 is range; 2 is single day; 3 is the closing time
            If M.submatches(0) <> "" And M.submatches(1) <> "" Then
                For I = .Match(M.submatches(0), arWkDays, 0) To .Match(M.submatches(1), arWkDays, 0)
                    V(I - 1) = CDate(M.submatches(3) & "PM")
                Next I
            ElseIf M.submatches(2) <> "" Then
                V(.Match(M.submatches(2), arWkDays, 0) - 1) = CDate(M.submatches(3) & "PM")
            End If
            End With
        Next M
    End If
End With

ClosingTime = V

End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: I'm impressed.  Will it handle "interleaved" schedules, like M,W,F 9PM; T&T 11PM; or M&F 11 PM; Tue-Thu 9PM?

Comment: @fixer1234 The UDF is designed to handle data in the format(s) indicated by the original poster, as well as the logic of specifying either a single day, or a range of days.  Your example conforms to neither the format nor the logic of his expressions, so, no, the UDF would not handle that sort of expression.  However, given a comprehensive list of possibilities, so long as they are unambiguous, one could certainly construct a UDF that should work.

Comment: Close enough for government work.  +1

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Beautifully done. I haven't the faintest idea of the inner workings, but I tried thoroughly to break/confuse it and thus far have been unsuccessful. Very well made; Thank you for this.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe You are welcome.  The third paragraph describes what the regex looks at for the days; in addition, it extracts the time by looking for something that could be a time that is followed by the letter `p`.  If there are two days, it "fills in" the days between with the same closing time.  If only a single day, then it just applies the closing time to that date.  So paragraphs that don't conform won't work.  But it seems you don't have that issue in your data.

Answer (score 2):

I patched something together just to demonstrate the concept.  I'm sure this could be greatly streamlined with array formulas, but I was going for fast and easy to follow.

[image: screenshot1]

#### Explanation of the structure

Columns A and B are your sample data.  Note that I've included the store ID on each line.  This is just good practice in case the data gets scrambled, but not necessary.  You want closing times by day for each store and the stores have varying numbers of records, so I added a store summary line that will eventually contain an entry for each day.  The summary lines could be in a separate "report" of your output.

The task requires converting day information into usable form, and that is a mess.  Trying to write formulas to parse your records would be a nightmare given the variety of formats.  The approach I used instead is to build a list of "day" phrases as you encounter them, and manually translate each phrase once.

This also allows you to save a few entries by using lowest common denominator phrases.  For example, you used three-letter day abbreviations in the first example, but used "Thurs" in the second.  Using "Mon-Thu" will match both cases.

Most of your day spans are hyphenated, but you used "&" for "Fri & Sat".  On the chance that there might also be a "Fri-Sat", I just made that another entry in the list.

If the capitalization is not all the same,you could either manually clean it up, or use text functions to force everything to upper or lower case.

In this screenshot, I've hidden some columns temporarily.  The day phrase list starts in column N, with the day phrases in row 1.  You just add another phrase in the next column as needed.  Row 2 contains the day list associated with the phrase, using standard Excel day numbering.  I made holidays day 0 (I see it isn't showing in my screenshot, but S2 would be `0`.  Mon/Wed/Fri would be 246.

#### First formula

The cells under the day translations all use the same formula, so copy and paste as needed:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(N$1,$B3)),"",N$2)
```

This looks for the day phrase of the column heading in the schedule record of that row.  If the phrase is found, the cell gets the included day list from row 2, otherwise it's blank.  So for each schedule record, one phrase should match and that's the day list that will show for the row.

#### Helper Columns

[image: screenshot 2]

This screenshot reveals two helper columns to keep the explanation simple.  Column L summarizes the day list.  There will be only one matching entry and this just consolidates it.  Cell L3 contains:

```
=SUM(N3:AB3)
```

You can make the range arbitrarily large so you don't need to adjust it every time you add a day phrase.  That can be copied down the column as needed.

Column K contains the close time extracted from the schedule record.  The formula in L3 is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",REPT(MID(B3,LEN(TRIM(B3))-5,1),IF(MID(B3,LEN(TRIM(B3))-5,1)="1",2,1))&":00pm")
```

Any method of parsing this will be messy because the times have different numbers of digits.  This formula locates the closing hour unit digit.  It uses it one time if it is `6` or `9` and repeats the `1` if the time is `11`.  It then concatenates the ":00pm".  I added an ISBLANK test because my layout has some blank rows.

#### Decoding times by day

This brings us to the meat of the problem.

[image: screenshot 3]

This screenshot reveals a column for each day of the week plus holidays.  Again there is a single formula that is used for all cells except the summary rows.  Cell C3 contains:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(COLUMN()-3,$L3)),"",$K3)
```

My example starts the days in the third column, and the first of these is Holidays, which is coded as day 0.  This formula calculates the day number associated with the column and checks to see whether it is in the day list for that row.  If it is, it gets the extracted time value for the row, otherwise a blank.  So every day that is included in the record's day phrase gets the record's closing time.  Days not covered by the schedule for that row get nothing.

The complete daily schedule for the week is a consolidation of the rows for that store.  If the summary rows are elsewhere, you could use the store ID to identify the rows that go into each summary.

For this concept demo, I didn't get fancy with the summary row.  Cell C5 is:

```
=C3&C4
```

Cell C11 is:

```
=C7&C8&C9&C10
```

This could be automated based on row counts, or the summary row could be created directly instead of consolidating the component rows.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. From Excel 2016, Power Query is built in to the Data ribbon under "Get and Transform" section.

Power Query can start from an existing Excel Table. The crucial trick is to use the "Split Column by Delimiter" option to split on the right-most delimiter.  You can then work backwards splitting the time portions of the string off into new Time columns.

A Query result can be delivered as an Excel Table. You can build this without writing any macro or function code - you just click around in the Power Query window.

I built a working solution which you can download from my OneDrive and try out:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

It's the file: **Power Query demo - Parsing non-standard date time data**